# Kendo Tooltip content chnages dynamically depending on the other 2 row data

Tags: javascript, tooltip, kendo-grid

I have grid which has around 8 columns, 8th column has the delete button. When the user hovers over the delete button tooltip should appear with some content. Now the content in the tooltip depends on the row value from 6th and 7th column. Consider if the row value of 6th column is 'Yes' and row value of 7th column is "No", tooltip content will be Hello and as the row value of 6th and 7th column changes tooltip content will also change. Below is my code, but i am unable to get that.

```
function initializeGrid() {
            $("#wellboreGrid").kendoGrid({
                filterable: true,
                resizeable: true,
                reorderable: true,
                columnMenu: true,
                scrollable: false,
                dataBound: function (e) {
                    debugger;
                    $("#wellboreGrid").find(".k-button").kendoTooltip({
                        content:e.data.item.ExistingAssn=="Yes" && e.data.item.ExistingGeologic=="NO" ? "Hello" : e.data.item.ExistingAssn=="Yes" && e.data.item.ExistingGeologic=="YES" ? "EXIT":e.data.item.ExistingAssn=="No" && e.data.item.ExistingGeologic=="YES" ? "WHAT" : Error,

                        width: 100,
                        height: 60,
                        position: "bottom",
                    });
                },
                columns: [
                { field: "FacilityId", title: "", hidden: true },
                { field: "FacilityName", title: "Shell Name" },
                { field: "shortName", title: "Shell Short Name" },
                { field: "ApiNumber", title: "API Number" },
                { field: "InService", title: "Service Status" },
                { field: "State", title: "State" },
                { field: "ExistingAssn", title: "Existing Association", format: "{0:c}" },
                { field: "ExistingGeologic", title: "Existing Geologic", format: "{0:c}" },
                { field: "LithoStratColoumnId", title: "", hidden: true },
                { field: "GeoIntervalId", title: "", hidden: true },
                { command: [{ click: deleteItem, text: "X" }], title: "Delete" }
                ]
            });
            $("#dvshowWellbore").attr("style", "display:inline;float: left;font-weight:bolder;font-style:italic;padding-bottom:10px;padding-left:15px;font-size:15px;");
            $("#wellboreGrid").find('.k-grid-header .k-header').css('font-weight', 'bold');

        };
```